# Can you iterate in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

I'm new to LaTeX and I must say that I am really struggling with it. I discovered the \newcommand command that is kind of like a function/method in regular programming languages. You can give it arguments and everything.

I was wondering though, can I somehow iterate in LaTeX? Basically, what I would like to do is create a table with N+1 columns where the first row just contains a blank cell and then the numbers 1, 2, ..., N in the other columns. I only want to give N as an argument to this 'function' (newcommand).

Here is an example of something that might look like what I'm looking for (although obviously this won't work):

```
\newcommand{\mytable}[2]{  
\begin{tabular}{l|*{#1}{c|}} % table with first argument+1 columns  
  for(int i = 1; i <= #1; i++) "& i" % 'output' numbers in different columns  
  \\\hline  
  letters & #2 % second argument should contain actual content for row  
  \\\hline  
\end{tabular}  
}
```

Call it with:

```
\mytable{3}{a & b & c}
```

Output should be:

```
        | 1 | 2 | 3 |
--------+---+---+---+
letters | a | b | c |
--------+---+---+---+
```

Does anyone know if something like this is possible?

Thanks!

Comment: as LaTeX is a macro package to TeX and TeX is Turing-complete, it should be possible, although you would need some serious TeX hacking

Comment: possible duplicate of [iteration in latex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561791/iteration-in-latex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auntie Google says [yes](http://mathematics.nsetzer.com/latex/latex_for_loop.html).

Comment: That code requires the user to name the counter, which means nesting loops is fragile.

Answer (score 4):

Just make the following into a new command and be sure to use package `ifthen`.

```
\begin{tabular}{l|*{10}{c|}}
\newcounter{count}
\whiledo{\value{count}<10}{
\ifthenelse{\value{count}=0}{}{\the\value{count}}
\ifthenelse{\value{count}<9}{&}{\\}
\stepcounter{count}
}
letters&a&b&c&d&e&f&g&h&i\\
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `\loop` or `\repeat` tokens. Or the [`multido`](https://ctan.org/pkg/multido) package.

Answer (score 2):

Sure it's possible.  You can also recur.  eplain has iteration macros in it, see, eg, [here](http://tex.loria.fr/texlive-htmldoc/eplain/eplain_6.html).

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility (if you're lazy like me) is [perltex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/perltex/)