# Iteration in LaTeX

Tags: latex, for-loop, iteration

I would like to use some iteration control flow to simplify the following LaTeX code.

```
  \begin{sidewaystable}
  \caption{A glance of images}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{| c ||c| c| c |c| c|| c |c| c|c|c| }
  \hline
  \backslashbox{Theme}{Class} &\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Class 0} & \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Class 1}  \\
  \hline

  \hline
          1 &
          \includegraphics[scale=2]{../../results/1/0_1.eps}
          &\includegraphics[scale=2]{../../results/1/0_2.eps}
          &\includegraphics[scale=2]{../../results/1/0_3.eps}
          &\includegraphics[scale=2]{../../results/1/0_4.eps}
          &\includegraphics[scale=2]{../../results/1/0_5.eps}
          &\includegraphics[scale=2]{../../results/1/1_1.eps}
          &\includegraphics[scale=2]{../../results/1/1_2.eps}
          &\includegraphics[scale=2]{../../results/1/1_3.eps}
          &\includegraphics[scale=2]{../../results/1/1_4.eps}
          &\includegraphics[scale=2]{../../results/1/1_5.eps}      \\
  \hline

  ...  % similarly for 2, 3, ..., 22

  \hline
          23 &
          \includegraphics[scale=2]{../../results/23/0_1.eps}
          &\includegraphics[scale=2]{../../results/23/0_2.eps}
          &\includegraphics[scale=2]{../../results/23/0_3.eps}
          &\includegraphics[scale=2]{../../results/23/0_4.eps}
          &\includegraphics[scale=2]{../../results/23/0_5.eps}
          &\includegraphics[scale=2]{../../results/23/1_1.eps}
          &\includegraphics[scale=2]{../../results/23/1_2.eps}
          &\includegraphics[scale=2]{../../results/23/1_3.eps}
          &\includegraphics[scale=2]{../../results/23/1_4.eps}
          &\includegraphics[scale=2]{../../results/23/1_5.eps}      \\
  \hline

  \end{tabular}
  \end{sidewaystable}
```

I learn that the [forloop package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/forloop/) provides the `for` loop. But I am not sure how to apply it to my case? Or other methods not by forloop?

---

If I also want to simply another similar case, where the only difference is that the directory does not run from 1, 2, to 23, but in some arbitrary order such as 3, 2, 6, 9,..., or even a list of strings such as dira, dirc, dird, dirb,.... How do I make the LaTeX code into loops then?

Comment: please check if the accepted answer is still the best choice. The highest voted answer has almost three times as many up votes! Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Something like this will take care of the body of your tabular:

```
\newcounter{themenumber}
\newcounter{classnumber}
\newcounter{imagenumber}
\forloop{themenumber}{1}{\value{themenumber} < 24}{
    % \hline <-- Error here
    \arabic{themenumber}
    \forloop{classnumber}{0}{\value{classnumber} < 2}{
        \forloop{imagenumber}{1}{\value{imagenumber} < 6}{
            & \includegraphics[scale=2]{
                ../../results/\arabic{themenumber}/\arabic{classnumber}_\arabic{imagenumber}.eps
            }
        }
    }
    \\
    \hline
}
```

I had to comment out the first `\hline` because it gave me an error:

```
You can't use `\hrule' here except with leaders.
```

I'm not sure what that means; if you really cannot live without the double line, I can look into it more.

Also note that you have to use `<`; for example, `<= 24` will not work.

---

As to your update: I would simply declare a command that takes the argument that you're looping over. Something like this:

```
\newcommand\fordir[1]{do something complex involving directory named #1}

\fordir{dira}
\fordir{dirb}
\fordir{dirc}
\dots
```

Comment: Is the forloop command built-in?

Comment: No, it's from the [forloop package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/forloop) as stated in the question.

Answer (score 152):

You may use `pgffor` package, a tool provided by pgf. The basic syntax is:

```
\foreach \n in {0,...,22}{do something}
```

Notably, this for loop is not restricted to integers, for example:

```
\foreach \n in {apples,burgers,cake}{Let's eat \n.\par}
```

Comment: For some reason, I get a compilation error when importing the package `pgffor`.